# how to switch docker runtime between runc and oci

Tags: docker, fedora

I installed docker engine from Fedora's default repo.
After update fedora to 26, I got some very strange problem when using containers.

I found this in `docker info`:

> Runtimes: oci runc
>   Default Runtime: oci

Another computer with docker from `yum.dockerproject.org`, `docker info` only have runc:

> Runtimes: runc
>   Default Runtime: runc

I searched many place, but can not found any document about switch this runtimes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how I changed the default runtime from **runc** to **crun** on Ubuntu.

Simply edit `~/.config/docker/daemon.json`, and add `crun` to the list of runtimes, then set `crun` to be the default runtime.

```json
{
  "default-runtime": "crun",
  "runtimes": {
    "crun": {
      "path": "/usr/bin/crun"
    }
  }
}
```

Now restart docker service (`systemctl restart --user docker`)

*Note: If you are not running docker in **rootless** mode, you will need to instead edit `/etc/docker/daemon.json`.*

#### Sources

https://github.com/containers/crun/issues/37

Answer (score 1):

In [dockerd](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/), there is the option:

```
--default-runtime string                Default OCI runtime for containers (default "runc")
```

This is easier to configure in the [/etc/docker/daemon.json file](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/#daemon-configuration-file)

```
{
  "default-runtime": "runc"
}
```

And then from systemd, you can apply the change with a reload (no need to restart the engine and stop running containers):

```
systemctl reload docker
```

Note that a change in the daemon may not affect already created containers, so you'll likely need to create new containers to see the effect of this change.

For changing the runtime on a single container, you can do that from `docker run`. There is the following option (visible in `docker run --help`):

```
--runtime string                 Runtime to use for this container
```

The compose file has a similar [runtime: runc](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#runtime) syntax.

I'm not quite sure what docker meant by oci vs runc back when this question was asked, it was probably differentiating between a built-in runtime in the docker engine when they were forking off the runc code. That has long finished and you'll only see runc and containerd.runc runtimes in current docker installs. The reason the wording is confusing is because [runc is an OCI project](https://github.com/opencontainers/runc).